# Picture at top of article

Tags: phrase-requests, nouns, terminology, image-identification, publishing

Many online news articles and blog posts begin with a large image at the very top of the article, usually [showing the subject](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2018/04/huawei-matebook-x-pro-review-no-longer-just-a-macbook-clone/) or [something that causes association thereto](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2018/04/open-sesame-industrial-network-gear-hackable-with-the-right-username/) if the subject is not tangible enough to be pictured.

What is such an introductory illustration called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**lead or lede**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/lead)

> The introductory portion of a news story

It is common for an article's lead or information box to carry a **representative image‍** [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style/Images#Image_description_pages) This is for users of Wikipedia.

Here it is referenced as a **picture lead** in publications [article](http://web.archive.org/web/2018/http://successfulweb.com/resources/content/content-ip-lead-samples.shtml) [Illinois Univ](http://titan.iwu.edu/%7Ejplath/leads.html)